# Unable to show array of video using AVplayer

Tags: ios, json, avplayer

i have video url which i have to show on tableview. when i will click any of the cell, it will go to the detail view where the video will be played using AVPayer. once the video will end playing the next video will be played. when i am running the code, it the video is playing one after another . i am getting only the sound and video as a still image. when the nex video is playing only the image changes to another image. there is no video on the screen.

How to show all the playing video on the screen?

```
class DetailView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
var videoObject = [VideoData]()
private let vplayer = AVQueuePlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    videoPlayerView.player = vplayer
    addAllVideosToPlayer()
}


private func addAllVideosToPlayer() {
    for video in videoObject {

        guard let urlString = try? URL(string: video.url) else{return}
        print(video.url)
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: urlString)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        vplayer.insert(item, after: vplayer.items().last)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: vplayer)
        videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    }
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    vplayer.play()

}
}
```